# How to use 64 bit integers with boolector

Tags: smt

I'm trying to create a model using [boolector](https://github.com/Boolector/boolector) but I cannot find a way to represent a 64 bit integer. In fact, the number is always truncated to 32 bit. I think this is due to the fact that I'm using `boolector_int` which has an `uint32` as a parameter ( see the [doc](https://boolector.github.io/docs/cboolector_index.html) )

Can anybody suggest me a way to represent such a number? Honestly at the moment I cannot see the reason why it is possible to create a `boolector_bitvec_sort` of 64 bits and `boolector_int` only accept `uint32`.

Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify, the number 2**60 is represented as (model
  (define-fun v_0 () (_ BitVec 64) #x0000000000000000)
)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `boolector_int` function is intended for conversion from an actual `int32_t`. And similarly `boolector_unsigned_int` is intended for conversion from an actual `uint32_t`.

For your use case, use one of the functions:

- `boolector_const`
- `boolector_constd`
- `boolector_consth`

which essentially accept strings as arguments to put your constant in. See: https://github.com/Boolector/boolector/blob/ae2a749b858b42c06d436353d8c1857b05021b2e/src/boolector.h#L707-L743

It's a bit roundabout, but essentially you'll first convert your constant to a string and then pass it on. (Different variants essentially allow for binary, decimal, and hexadecimal representation.) This way you don't have to worry about how wide that constant really is, since these functions also take the destination `sort` as an argument.